# Sequelize eager load

Tags: sequelize.js

I meet a situation which needs to load the model itself as a child field.

For example:

the model `USER` contains a `foreignkey` called: `reporter_id`, I used the `include` to preload/eagerload the ***REPORTER***, which is a ***USER*** model also.

**SERVICE**:

```
...
const result = await models.user.findAll({
    where: {
      id: { [Op.in]: [11, 22] },
      status: { [Op.in]: [1, 2] },
    },
    include: [
      {
        model: models.user,
        as: 'reporter',
        attributes: ['id', 'name', ...],
      },
    ],
  });
...
```

**MODEL**:

```
const user = sequelize.define(
    'user',
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
      ...
      report_to: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      ...
    },
    {
      tableName: 'xxxx',
      timestamps: false,
      underscored: true,
    }
  );
  user.associate = function(models) {
    // reporter associations
    user.hasOne(models.user, {
      as: 'reporter',
      sourceKey: 'id',
      foreignKey: 'reporter_id',
    });
  };
)
```

The result comes nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to load an associated user as a reporter by using `reporter_id` foreign key column then you need to change `hasOne` to `belongsTo` (and you can remove `sourceKey` because it point to a primary key which is a default case).

```js
// reporter associations
    user.belongsTo(models.user, {
      as: 'reporter',
      foreignKey: 'reporter_id',
    });
```

Comment: Thx, it works fine. One more confusing point: 
I'm using a user loading another user as a reporter, in the perspective of lexical, the reporter is loaded by the user, so, I didn't even thought to using belongsto.